# Show callback after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is pretty a newby question but I can't figure this one out because it is a different approach/way of writing then I'm used to!

I'm using the app "[Back in Stock](http://help.backinstock.org/article/81-javascript-api)" for a webshop that's **not** shopify but something like that. This app shows a modal when a product is out of stock to register your email to recieve an update.

Further I created my own modal because of translation issues and more country related stuff.

I'm having trouble to create or to run a function to show a success or error message when I click a button.

The docs say that this is the way to grab all messages:

```
var notificationCallback = function(data) {
    var msg = '';
    if (data.status == 'OK') {
      msg = data.message; // just show the success message
    } else { // it was an error
      for (var k in data.errors) {  // collect all the error messages into a string
        msg += data.errors[k].join();
       }
    }
    alert(msg);
  }
```

I have created a function that shows the popup and handles the submit:

```
<button class="notify_button pp pull-right" data-product-id="{{ product.id }}" data-variant-id="{{ product.vid }}" onclick="notify_me_function(this,event);">{{ 'Email when available' | t }}</button>

function notify_me_function(el ,event){
  var variantId = $(el).data('variant-id');
  var productId = $(el).data('product-id');
  var itemName = $(el).closest('.item').find('.item-name').text();

  $('#notify__').modal('show');      


  $('#notify__ #notify_button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $('#notify__ .form-horizontal input').val();
    var $container = $('.completed_message');

    // this piece of code below is also from the docs /////////
    BIS.create(email, variantId, productId).then(notificationCallback);

   //something like this?? ///
   $container.txt(msg);

  });

}
```

How do I show the `msg` from `notificationCallback` everytime I click the submit button inside the modal?

Answer (score 0):

In your notify modal dialog html markup put something like

```
<div id="#puttexthere"></div>
```

then you can do

```
$('#puttexthere').text(msg);
```

Hopefully what you need.